# how to use Firefox but pretend that I am using iPhone (to use Firebug to examine the page design)

Tags: iphone, firefox, safari, firebug, ipod

Is there a way to use Firefox and Firebug but pretend it is iPhone's Safari by faking the User Agent string?  I want to use Firefox to examine the Amazon or Gmail sites and see how the page is laid out for iPhone... just for fun and for experiment.  Is there a way?  thanks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fake the user agent string using the instructions great_llama provided, but remember that Firefox is not Safari and it probably won't lay out the page identically.  If you're on a Windows or OS X machine you can use Safari to see how it will look with a higher degree of accuracy.

Comment: In Safari, turn on the "Developer" menu in the Options - one of the submenus lets you choose your user agent, and includes both iPhone and iPod Touch.

Comment: Oh, and you might be able to use Firebug Lite in Safari - don't know, because I've never tried it, but it's basically a JS file that gets injected into the page.

Answer (score 1):

[Here are some instructions](http://paininthetech.com/2007/10/03/fake-iphone-user-agent/) on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [emulator](http://www.testiphone.com/) and you can run your dev version. You can then use firebug on the emulator frame